# Overwriting in a random access file

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a random access file opened in "r+b" mode with records of equal length. Can I change the contents of a record after reading it and overwrite in place?

I tried the following code but on running I get: Segmentation fault(core dumped)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   struct tala {
      int rec_no;
      long file_no;
   };
   FILE *file_locking;
   struct tala t,f;
   file_locking = fopen("/path/to/my/file.bin", "rb+");
   t.rec_no = 1;
   t.file_no = 3;
   if (fwrite(&t, sizeof(struct tala),1,file_locking)==0)
      printf("Error opening file");
   t.rec_no=0;
   rewind(file_locking);
   if (fwrite(&t, sizeof(struct tala),1,file_locking)==0)
      printf("Error opening file");
   rewind(file_locking);
   if (fread(&f, sizeof(struct tala),1,file_locking)==0)
      printf("Error opening file");
   printf("\n %d",f.rec_no);
   printf("\n %ld", f.file_no);
   fclose(file_locking);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening mode of Binary files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000430/opening-mode-of-binary-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Just remember to always `fseek` between reads and writes.

Quote the `fopen` man page:

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any order.  Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.

Extra tip: **always** check the return value of `fopen` and related functions, and handle errors (use `perror` or `strerror` to print out what failed).

Comment: @Mat...Will be gratefull if you check my code that i have now included

Comment: @Lipika: you're not checking the return value of `fopen`, so you're on your own.

Comment: Thanks...The problem was with fopen. Opening in rb+ mode does not create the file if it does not exist from before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The only thing to pay attention is that you have to call flush or a file positioning function before switching from output to input and call a file positioning function or be at end of file before switching from read to write.